# NavigationLink when destination's required parameter is from optional state variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

Navigating using optional state parameters really has me stumped.  The below code won't compile because `selectedObject` has to be nil coalesced because it's required by `NextView`, but I have nothing to coalesce it to. `NextView` requires this parameter, so an optional doesn't compile.  `MyObject` is a struct with all required attributes, so I don't have an empty constructor.  I'm using the `selected` state to manage when the navigation occurs, but it still won't compile because of the optional object.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @State var selected = false
    @State var selectedObject: MyObject? // optional because there isn't one until it's set by the child view

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: NextView(object: $selectedObject), isActive: self.$selected) {
            EmptyView()
       }
       // ... child view that when interacted with sets the selectedObject as a binding ... //
    }
}
```

```
struct MyObject: Identifiable, Codable {
   var property1: String
   var property2: String
   // .... many more ...
}
```

```
struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var object: MyObject // required binding
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("some stuff about my object")
    }
}
```

Comment: How selectedObject would be get value? which action or steps make selectedObject get some real value? PS: Your issue is simple but you need make sure we can create the issue for ourself! which as I see it missing needed code to create the issue.

Comment: A few options: 1) Pass in `Binding<MyObject?>` rather than `Binding<MyObject>`; 2) Make a lazy `NavigationLink` and force unwrap if you can be _sure_ `selectedObject` will never be `nil`; 3) Create a custom binding to pass in some other `MyObject` if `selectedObject` is `nil`. Up to you how you want to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely know that `selectedObject` will be present in time of link activation then you can solve this case passing on-the-fly created binding, like

```
    NavigationLink(destination: NextView(object:
        Binding(
            get: {selectedObject!},
            set: {selectedObject = $0}
        )), isActive: self.$selected) { EmptyView()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the key I was missing.  I also needed to wrap the `NavigationLink` in an `if` checking `self.$selected`.